# What java --add-opens parameter do i need to set to avoid below error?

Tags: java, oracle

I am trying to run an `Oracle Forms12c` app link in a `mac OS` , using `Java JRE 9.0.1` but i am getting the below error. Reading a lot in `google` , i found 2 possible solutions:

**solution 1:** use the parameter : **--illegal-access=permit** (but the error still continue, not working)

**Solution 2:** i think i can use (but no shure , since java is not a lenguage i work with) this parameter: **--add-opens** but i don't understand the syntaxt, so maybe you could help me how to complete the add-opens sintaxt considering the error log below.

Thanks in advance for any help, any other solution i can try will be highly appreciated !

**this is the link i run from mac terminal:**

> ```
> java -jar frmsal.jar -url http://192.168.10.190:9001/forms/frmservlet?config=My_app -t 30000
> ```

**this is the log i get:**

> Archive files will be downloaded in
>   /var/folders/zm/8hvr809x6jx9ck4lrlxjl92r0000gn/T/frmsal/12.2.1.2
>   directory
>
> WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred WARNING:
>   Illegal reflective access by oracle.forms.saa.FormsStandAloneApp
>   (file:/Users/MyUser/Desktop/MyApp/frmsal.jar) to method
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.addURL(java.net.URL)
>
> WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of
>   oracle.forms.saa.FormsStandAloneApp WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn
>   to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
>   WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future
>   release Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
>   object is not an instance of declaring class
>       at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
>   Method)
>       at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
>       at oracle.forms.saa.FormsStandAloneApp.getArchivesFromServer(Unknown
>   Source)
>       at oracle.forms.saa.FormsStandAloneApp.run(Unknown Source)
>       at oracle.forms.saa.FormsStandAloneApp.main(Unknown Source)

Comment: It looks like Oracle Forms has code that incorrectly assumes the application class loader is a URLClassLoader. This may be a case where you need to a submit a bug or check if there is a newer version of Oracle Forms  that supports JDK 9.